# function setParameter in AudioManager

Tags: android, audio

```
public void setParameters(String keyValuePairs) {
    AudioSystem.setParameters(keyValuePairs);
}
```

I found function setParameters in class AudioManager. It is described as "Sets a variable number of parameter values to audio hardware." So, Can I use this function to control the left speaker, right when playing video? 
And are there any examples of how this function works?

Comment: when using `MediaPlayer`? if so, try `MediaPlayer#setVolume`

Comment: I try using `mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f , 1.0f);` or 'mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f , 0.0f)' of `mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.0f , 1.0f)` but nothing changes

Comment: `_mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
 _mediaPlayer.start();`

Comment: `setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f)` - so what you hear after calling that?

Comment: the sound is still emitted. If you have used it successfully, please suggest me ?

Comment: hmmm, maybe try to call `setVolume` after starting your `MediaPlayer`? just a guess since it should work in any case imho

Comment: It's not working :((((( any other way?

Comment: no, no other way, the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)) say: *"Sets the volume on this player. This API is recommended for balancing the output of audio streams within an application. Unless you are writing an application to control user settings, this API should be used in preference to AudioManager.setStreamVolume(int, int, int) which sets the volume of ALL streams of a particular type. Note that the passed volume values are raw scalars in range 0.0 to 1.0. UI controls should be scaled logarithmically."*

Comment: Probably the fault due to the hardware of the device. Since I discovered the log `V/AmlogicPlayer: Set left volume:1.000000, right volume = 0.000000
    setVolume
 V/AmlogicPlayer: Amadec is not ready now, after start, set volume once more!`

Comment: Thanks for your help ^^